# How can I play Asari Vanguard effectively?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

The Asari Vanguard is way different than my previous style of play. With Human Vanguard I Charge in, I punch things in the face, and they die. Good times.

But the Asari Vanguard has different Skills; they seem much more focused around firearms than melee. I can't seem to make good use of Lift Grenades or Stasis (and I'm unsure how to upgrade either until I figure it out). The melee shockwave is nice but leaves me vulnerable. The teleport is nice and fast but eats my Barrier.

What can I do to play this character effectively in Multiplayer? What guns should I use and what skills are important?

Comment: asari vanguard, imo has one of the worst skill sets in multiplayer :/

Comment: @yx. I've been disappointed as well, but I might be doing it wrong...I never use any of the skills she has except Charge

Comment: yea, its because the asari vanguard, outside of lift grenades (which kinda suck when compared to other grenades anyway), don't have anything that's capable of dealing with an armored target.  Charge is pretty much suicide at higher difficulties.  If you are going to go all out weapons, might as well be an infiltrator at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's my favorite character at the moment at Silver/Gold chalanges. I prefer it to the asari adept, since vanguard is much more versatile.

It's the best to play a supporting role. => Stasis is the most important power. Use stasis to defend your team against enemies. Phantoms for example. Biotic Charge is useful to jump from one point to the other to help your other teammates if they need help. Additionally use it to tank, to take hits, since you can repair your shields (Don't tank much on Gold however, when attacked by large crowds. Could be useful however, to save your squadmate). Grenades are extremely useful too if used right against big hordes of enemies. I throw all three grenades at once some times.

I prefer a shotgun Disciple, since it makes cooldowns really short (160% for Disciple I, gets better with each upgrade). Geth Plasma Shotgun worked well too. You could use a pistol instead, but it's pain in the ... to kill high-level enemies using pistols. Additionally it's good to use it after a Biotic Charge.

Overall, it's not the character that earns many points, but it's extremely helpful for the team.

Comment: Not earning many points is a big part of what I'm noticing...as human vanguard I almost always take home the most points in bronze/silver :P/ Sounds like this might be more helpful for Gold though, where Melee isn't quite as safe.

Comment: I don't really need many points :DIt's fun to play supporting role.

Comment: I suppose, it's just an entirely different role...and I was looking so forward to the shockwave melee...

Comment: What's your build?

Answer (score 2):

I saw one Asari Vanguard top the charts on several of my silver matches in a row. I love my Asari Adept, and my favorite kill strategy is stasis bubble then headshots with my carnifex; it works better on standard mobs than spamming warp. This vanguard had the same strategy--stasis and headshots--but used the vanguard talents and a mattock, scoring better dps. He didn't use the charge hardly at all, and he demolished anything without armor.

Comment: you can't head shot anything other than the weak minions on silver and up with a carnifex as most enemies will drop out of stasis after 1 shot, unless their shields or health is already down or something.  The only class I know of that can head shot everything other than banshees, brutes, and primes is the infiltrator with maxed out damage boost

Answer (score 1):

this is how I play as the asari vanguard:

1) try to level out everything except stasis, stasis is a great skill but the other one are better.

2) when maxing out lift granades go for range damage and the extra granade, forget about duration or the slam ability.

3)use the geth shotgun, it has high damage and long range so you can stil hit the targets at a distance, you can also charge it for more damage. and equip no other weapons to increase the recharge speed.

4)we're going for a hit and run attacks. shoot them from afar then rush in to finish the job. pop out the grandes and melee and use the shotgun.

5)don't rush blindly, it will only get you killed. resulting in a loss because your team tried to save you. you dont have nova and melee takes longer so you are more likely to get killed.

6)when using granades to kill groups try to hit a person in that group. the granade explodes on contact. dont worry if you miss they will still go of but it can be less effective.

7) using granedes and only one weapon can lead to a situation where you're out of ammo. so make sure you know where all the resupply points are and make habite of swining by them whenever you can.

additional details:
go for the hit 2 addition targets with the biotic rush. that way you will stun more targets when going in.
dodge only when needed because it will drain your barrier.
train on bronze with those granades. use them whenever you can whilst training. hitting the target will mean more kills.
you can hit the cerberus shield guys by pinballing a granade via the wall. there is no faster way to kill them

Answer (score 1):

The asari vanguard is freaking imba!
Stasis, geth plasma shotgun and lift grenade is all you need!! Forget about biotic charge.

Just bubble stasis everything and rip em apart with the shotgun! Mine is lvl IX and I'm getting scores 120,000 per match on gold.

The downside is that everybody  hates you  for getting all the kills.

Answer (score 1):

I do very well with an Asari Vanguard.

What I did when I started out:

I didn't level stasis or lift grenade, all I did was max out charge and the 2 passives to make it safer. Then I would equip a shotgun and basicly charge everything over and over with no loss to shield cause they go to full everytime I do it.

In the cooldown periods, I use a shotgun on people's faces or heavy melee (which I upgraded as much as possible with the passive, it does leave you open but when you kill stuff in one hit even through shields and armor there's not much left standing to shoot you.)

At higher levels I would max stasis and with a quicker cooldown that I'm sure you have by now, use stasis first, then charge the person with stasis to get a biotic explosion. This kills the guy in stasis and possibly damages people around him, then clean house with shotgun and charge spam.

I've never used grenades effecivly, they seem pointless so I don't even put a point in them. Hope this helps someone, it works for me as I've beaten other vangaurds and their novas with this tactic. However if your not playing competitively (or even if you are this some times steal kills) you can stasis ppl when they charge and get a bio explosion which counts as ur kill if killed by the explosion.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna leave you some links to a couple questions that will help you. Most of which ive answered myself

[How can i play vanguard effectively?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54595/how-can-i-play-vanguard-effectively-in-mass-effect-3), [what types of weapons best suit each class in multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/what-types-of-weapons-best-suit-each-class-in-multiplayer/55879#55879), [How can i effectively solo the co-op mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53633/how-can-i-effectively-solo-the-co-op-mode/55780#55780), and [How do Vanguards handle silver and gold multiplayer matches?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56091/how-do-vanguards-handle-silver-and-gold-multiplayer-matches)

There is a lot of info that will help you in these questions. Specially ones that are somewhat similiar

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Jupotter thanks for the advice and link im still learning so that was useful information.